# twilio sipendpoint call is failed

Tags: twilio

I have used following code make a call to twilio sipendpoint. But i'm getting call failed status.

The call flow is like this when agent click on customer number, first i'm connecting to agent to his sip url  like this `sip:name@sip.twilio.com` on request call back i'll connect to customer number using dial verb.

The sip log gives following error
X-Twilio-Error: 400: Bad value for header: X-Twilio-OutboundRouteCount

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$client->account->calls->create(
                            'name',
                            'sip:name@sip.twilio.com',
                            'http://twiliocallback,
                            array(  
                                    'Record' => true,
                                    'Method' => "GET",
                                    'StatusCallback' => 'http://url,
                                    'StatusCallbackMethod' => 'GET',
                                    'StatusCallbackEvent' => array("initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"),
                                    'SipAuthPassword' => '****',
                                    'SipAuthUsername' => '****'

                            ));
```

Comment: Do you have the CallSID?

Comment: Hi Guys, I have found the answer, At this time internal routing of SIP calls within Twilio is not supported i.e. dialing .sip.twilio.com addresses from a Twilio number.